# Using a class-object's function output later in the program [Python 2.7]

Tags: python, function, class, object

I would first like to apologize for how much of a beginner I am, however I have hit this wall after many other hurdles. The basis of this is to retrieve a value from a website, modify it using variables and print the final value. My knowledge of classes and objects is very very minimal. I just cannot figure out how I can take the value *numTotal* from my function *getPlays* and use it later to print as *Final*. The value prints correctly from within the function I just need to store that value for later use as a variable.

```
class GetPlaycount(object):

    def getPlays(self):
        print "Working"
        browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\Python27\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\phantomjs.exe')
        browser.get('https://osu.ppy.sh/u/4973241')
        time.sleep(1)
        Plays = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="general"]/div[8]').text 
        numPlays = int(re.sub('[^0-9]', '', Plays))
        numTime = int(numPlays) * int(numLength)
        numTotal = int(numTime) * float(numVar)
        print int(numTotal)
        return numTotal


myClassObject = GetPlaycount()

myClassObject.getPlays()

Final = ????

print Final

raw_input("wait")
```

Thank you for your help and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly

```
final = myClassObject.getPlays()
print final
```

Should be all you need.

Comment: Just tried that, it does print what I need but it runs the function again rather than taking the original value? http://prntscr.com/7qwbq5

Comment: @JesseAshmore, you are already printing in your `getPlays()` method, that's why you see it printing twice.

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور
I understand, but it is actually taking the time to run the whole thing again, hence the "Working" twice. It runs it, prints the value, then runs it again and prints again. Can I not run it once, save the output, and print the output rather than running for the output each time. It is now taking twice as long for the program to finish.

Comment: That's because you are calling it twice ..@JesseAshmore